# I always need to restart Kernel, when i m changing the value of variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, jupyter-notebook

Code is working, it s a phone parser, i have a problem with Jupyter Notebook. When i change the value of ***txt*** and run code, nothing happens, kernel running, but nothing happens. Only if i stop and restart kernel and run Jupyter again, it will be working. I can't understand how to fix this problem

```
import requests
import re
import urllib3
import pandas as pd

urllib3.disable_warnings()

dict_urls = {}

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['url','phone'])

txt = u'''100 urls'''
url = txt.split('\n')
for urls in url:
    try:
        url = 'http://www.' + urls
        print(url)
        phone_numbers = []
        r = requests.get(url, verify=False, timeout = 50.000)
        res = re.findall(r'tel:(.*?)>', r.text)
        for phone in res:
            phone = phone.split('\"')[0]
            if phone not in phone_numbers and phone != '$[properties.phone]':
                 phone_numbers.append(phone)
                 print(phone)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        continue

    dict_urls[url] = phone_numbers
```

Comment: start and stop `kernel` ?

Comment: You have a timeout of 50 seconds for the request, have you tried waiting for the kernel for 50 seconds? Maybe there is a url that does not respond, in that case it will not fail until the request times out.

Comment: @JulianMinde i add timeout recently, because i have a problem with ReadTimeoutError